# can I use ansible to start docker swarm services without compose?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

how can I ssh into a service created by docker swarm? I have created a service using docker stack and the yaml file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: "myimage1"
    expose:
      - "8080"
```

and I validated that the service is running but I'm not sure how to ssh into the service(container) that was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ssh into container, you would need ssh service running inside container. This is generally not a good practice. 
To get access to container shell without having ssh running, you can use:
docker exec -ti  bash/sh

Ansible has docker modules for managing containers and images(http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html#docker-container, http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html#docker-image)